# How to get all elements in a hybrid app in android/ios using appium, selenium and java

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, appium, appium-ios

Am using java+appium+Webdriver for automating mobile app. Need an idea on how to get all the strings in the app page and store it somewhere(excel etc)

Comment: try using `List<WebElement>'  finding all the elements using `xpath("//')`